# Play Developer Console Error (Android Version 12 Issue)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Comment: hi, if you did you fix it, can you share us any solution?

Comment: if you use intent-filter in your application then please put this (android:exported="true") attribute to your activity in your manifest. If you are using a receiver then put true if your receiver is accessed by other apps, otherwise, put false.

Comment: I know this and I did it but it didn't work for me. I lowered the targetversion to 30, changed all intent filters and receivers of the libraries in the merged manifest, and upgraded it to targetversion 31 again, but it still didn't work. When I upgraded to targetversion 31, the changes I made in the merged manifest were gone.

Comment: then you have to share your sample code and the manifest file.